# Некорректное отображение представления в инспекторе

Tags: android, android-studio, view, layout

В инспекторе мое представление выглядит вот так:[image]

Хотя на самом деле (вид с установленного приложения) вот такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть в инспекторе вьюхи как будто вдавлены внутрь, странные тени, контура. 
**Как это можно исправить? Кто с этим сталкивался? И норма ли это?**


Что уже делал для исправления:
1. Менял AppTheme
2. Перетыкал уже все кнопки-свойства вот тут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Иногда встречал такое, просто игнорировал, ведь всё равно самое полное представление о результате можно получить только попробовав на реальном девайсе.

Comment: У меня так же. Скорей всего так отображаются границы элементов в LinearLayout.

Comment: У меня в визуальном редакторе по умолчанию именно такие контуры в LinearLayout. В работающей программе такого нет. Android Studio 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная тень в визуальном редакторе показывает направление ориентации в контейнере `LinearLayout` - если тень снизу и сверху ,то ориентация вертикальная (`android:orientation="vertical"`), если по бокам - горизонтальная (`android:orientation="horizontal"`). Естественно, что в приложении никакой тени не будет.

ответ на [английском stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54211447/7566397)